# Compile Error "Expected:end of statement in vb6"

Tags: vb6

When i define an initialize a variable i get the compile time error as "Expected:End of statement". The code is :

```
Dim i as integer=1
```

Answer (score 5):

The VB6 compiler does not let you declare and initialise a variable in one line (like you can in VB.NET).

So you have to declare it on one line and initialise it on another:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
```

If you want to have both statement on the same line you can use a colon:

```
Dim i As Integer : i = 1
```

But you can only do this inside a procedure and not in a module, form or class declaration

Answer (score 3):

```
dim i as integer
i=1
```

You need to split declaring a variable and assigning its value.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a value to a variable you are declaring in VB6, UNLESS it is a constant

```
' BAD
Dim i as Integer = 1

' GOOD
Dim i As Integer
Const i As Integer = 1
```